# Java scanner completely bypasses String input

Tags: java

I have a bit of a problem with a part of my code.

```
if (option1 == 1){
   //Add Movie
   System.out.print('\u000C');
   System.out.println(">>Add Movie<<");
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.print("Title: ");
   String title = scan.nextLine();
   System.out.print("Year: ");
   int year = scan.nextInt();
}
```

When i execute the code, it prints out,

```
Title: Year:
```

completely skipping the scan.nextLine(); so I'm unable to put any input for it.

Does anyone have an idea on why it is doing this?

**EDIT:**

I've managed up to fix this. Turns out if was a `scan.nextLine();` error and it had not fully moved to a new line. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: i doubt that this is your only code. It rather looks like you have another call of `nextInt` or some other `nextFoo` method (excluding `nextLine`) before you do `System.out.print("Title: ");`. You are most likely just catching the carriage return that you didn´t catch beforehand. Assuming i am right you could check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods) for further information.

Comment: Kindly show your full code.

Comment: Please show full code (Also code that scan `option1`). Better if you paste full class after removing unnecessary code.

Comment: @Zaman sorry what do you mean by code scan?

Comment: @Preet, he mean the code which take input for `option1` variable. Kindly share your full code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe before this code there has a `next()` family

```
input.nextInt();
input.next();

input.next....(); //Excluding input.nextLine()
```

Which doesn't consume extra newline, that consumed by your statement

```
String title = scan.nextLine();
```

to resolve this you may add extra `nextLine()` before those code.

So this code should work

```
scan.nextLine(); //Consume extra new line
System.out.print("Title: ");
String title = scan.nextLine();
System.out.print("Year: ");
int year = scan.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the code is working fine-

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("title: ");
    String title=scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("year: ");
    int year=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("title is: "+title+" and year is: "+year);
```

the output i am getting is this-

```
title: king
year: 2015
title is: king and year is: 2015
```

Answer (score -1):

tyr this code.

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Title: ");
String title = scan.nextLine();
```